# Django get renamed uploaded image url

Tags: django, url, file-upload, django-forms

I am working on a project that will allow the user to upload image. The uploaded image will later on displayed and be passed to another form. To do this, I need to get the image url of the uploaded image. Here is my code:

```
def inputImage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageDetailsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            message = "The image was successfully uploaded!"
            imageName = str(request.FILES['image'].name)
            imageURL = settings.MEDIA_URL + "/" + imageName
        return render(request,'success.html', {'message': message, 'image': imageURL})
```

The code is working, however a problem would occur if the user uploads a file with an existing filename at the storage. To avoid conflict, Django automatically renames the file but the line

```
imageName = str(request.FILES['image'].name)
```

only returns the original filename of the uploaded image. I have also tried to use

```
imageName = str(form.cleaned_data['image'].name)
```

but still no changes.  It returns **"/media//1.png"**  instead of **"/media//1_0rnKMaT.png"**

Any ideas on how to get the URL of the current upload in Django?

Edit:
here is my models.py:

```
class ImageDetails(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=True)
```

and my forms.py

```
class ImageDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = ImageDetails
       fields= ('image')
       widgets = {
            'status': forms.HiddenInput(),
       }
```

Comment: Yes, but returns an error saying that the form has no 'image' object but it was actually one of the form fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the saved model instance through `form.instance`, so you should be able to get the name of the saved file with `form.instance.image_field_name.name` where `image_field_name` is the name of the image field in your model.